# Vacuum tubes versus solid state in specialist audio

Tags: dsp, vacuum-tube

There is obviously a large body of opinion that believes the use of vacuum tube amplifiers enhances some types of music.

My question is simple: Given that modern DSP techniques can mimic just about any response, why are vacuum tubes still used rather than the far more reliable solid state DSP programmed to emulate a tube's response?

Comment: This will attract primarily opinion-based answers.

Comment: Why do people play the lottery? Why are people afraid of flying? Same answer.

Comment: curses, too slow.  Should have posted a garbage answer.

Comment: The "tube" myth survives in the audio recording hobby.  Some years ago, one of the less credulous publications ran tests on a selection of microphone preamps at various prices.  The conclusion was that, when not intentionally run into overload, they all sounded the same.  The readership, however, steadfastly refuses to believe this, and discussion of "high-end" equipment still abounds.
http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/dec12/articles/preamp-results.htm

Comment: How can DSP emulate a tube if it's amplified with transistors? Like commercials for new LCD TV, look how fine picture you get on our new LCD TV while you are looking at it from your old TV.

Comment: a little bit of 2nd and 3rd harmonic makes most music sound a bit 'richer', bottles are attractive to look at, niche, and expensive. What's not to like, if you've got the money, and want the bragging rights.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič You characterise the response of a tube amp, design an algorithmic equivalent and apply it to the audio signal before DA conversion and amplification. As long as the distortion of the solid state electronics is neglible there won't be any real difference.

Comment: @jms As far I know, the only difference when you listen music from transistor vs. tube amp is in the distortion due to their characteristics. And solid state amps do produce more distortion compared to tube, it is not neglible.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič "solid state amps do produce more distortion compared to tube"[citation needed]. It's not the choice of transistors or tubes but the amplifier topology that matters. Given enough budget and design effort, it's possible to design both vacuum tube and solid state amps with minimal distortion, at least for audio frequency circuits.

Comment: @jms citation: http://www.theaudioarchive.com/TAA_Resources_Tubes_versus_Solid_State.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"...large body of opinion..."* Well, in **my** opinion, some "tube people" shout louder than others. Most people listen to music from their phones, that's all solid state. If we count these in, the "tube people" are a minority. Indeed tube or no tubes is a matter of opinion and **personal** preference.

I think that there is a contradiction regarding audio equipment using tubes. On a testbench I can prove that tubes **can** add distortion (depending on how they're used), some people prefer this which is their good right. Listening to music is for enjoyment. If using tube based equipment gives someone more enjoyment then by all means, use tube based equipment.

Also in the audio scene "fidelity" and "neutral audio equipment" (which does not affect the audio signal) is regarded highly. Since tube amplifiers "do something" to the signal that contadicts with this. So if you would take this "something" and put it in a DSP then you deliberatly admit that you're changing the audio signal. Some "audio people" think this is "not done". Using tube based equipment is much more accepted and sometimes a sign of sophistication perhaps ?

So although I agree with you that the same or a very similar effect could probably be achieved using a DSP I don't think there's much commercial value to be earned.

And I guess many people just like the soft glow of a tube :-)